# What is the fastest way to convert a set of onset/offset times into a sampled square wave?

Tags: matlab

I have a `Mx2` matrix, named `events` where each row contains the onset and offset times of non-overlapping events. I'd like to construct a continuously sample signal that is equal to 1 for all points that are contained without any of the event times.  I know the timestamps at which I'd like to sample my signal.

For example given the two variables `eventTimes` and `ts`:

```
eventTimes = ...
[1 3;
 6 7;
 9 10];

ts = 1:10;
```

The resulting binary signal would be

```
binarySignal = [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1];
```

Current I solve this problem using anonymous function and closures, but its slow for very large data sets:

```
tmpFun = @(x) (x>=eventsTimes(:,1) & x<eventTimes(:,2));
binarySignal = cell2mat( arrayfun(tmpFun, ts, 'UniformOutput', 0) );
binarySignal = sum(binarySignal);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the first column to 1 and second column to -1 at the proper offset; then cumsum.

```
%% something like 
ts(eventTimes(:,1))=1; ts(eventTimes(:,2)+1)=-1; ts=cumsum(ts);
```